# Autodesk Forge Design Automation for Inventor AppBundle interop

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have created a few AppBundles that work well with Inventor, and I had to include the Autodesk.Inventor.interop.dll for the plugins to work.  Now I have a Plugin where I am deploying the dll but it can't resolve the dll or one of its dependencies.

Here is the actual log contents:

```
InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opening document: T:\Aces\Jobs\d5df421ba2ab4c098cfaef8b4db76b76\inputFiles\ThisJobAssembly.iam
InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opened
[07/29/2020 17:25:49] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Getting Inventor plug-in.
[07/29/2020 17:25:49] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Plug-in: Sample Assembly Automation Plugin
[07/29/2020 17:25:49]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: Sample Assembly Automation Plugin
[07/29/2020 17:25:49]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: Sample Assembly Automation Plugin
[07/29/2020 17:25:49] Could not load file or assembly 'Autodesk.Inventor.Interop, Version=23.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d84147f8b4276564' or one of its dependencies.
```

I can debug this plugin locally without issues.  I then took the entire output folder contents and tried that and received the same error. I have confirmed the dll in the output is version 23.1.0.0.

The only difference I see between this app and the previous is the implementation of a few iLogic assemblies.  Not sure if that would cause an issue or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this, I believe you can just set the "Embed Interop Types" to "True" for the Interop Dll in your Inventor Add-in project if it isn't already.
Another alternative would be to place the "Autodesk.Inventor.interop.dll" in your bundle along with your add-in Dll's.

Hope this helps. Let me know if it doesn't.